# Interfacing TLC1543CN adc with 8051

Tags: adc, clock, 8051

I am confused with the I/O clock input mentioned in this datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc1543.pdf

Do I need to output clock from this adc to 8051 or do I need to use an external crystal for both the TLC1543CN and 8051 together?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please provide a screenshot or quote text from the relevant section of the datasheet. It's helpful and the best format on StackExchange sites to have all of the necessary information provided in your question or answer without relying on web links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that confusing to read. There is a diagram near the end of the datasheet that shows a nominal arrangement between the a CPU (8051) and the ADC IC. And there is a section called "DETAILED DESCRIPTION" which makes things a lot clearer.

In general, the I/O Clock (which is really an input) line is used by your 8051 to "clock out," in serial mode, the prior reading. Your code is supposed to operate this clock (using a pin configured as an output pin) and to operate the chip select line (using another pin, if you have one, also configured as an output pin) and while that is happening also observe the data line (using yet another pin configured this time as an input.) You also may need to operate the address input pin for a part of the time you are also operating the clock line (using yet another 8051 pin configured as an output.)

The clock line also triggers other actions along the way, such as charging a capacitor array, or starting the next conversion near or at the end of a short series of clock cycles. The rate at which you clock this line, it says, cannot exceed 2.1MHz. It's not likely you'll need it to be that fast, as the conversion time appears to be about \$\le\$21\$\mu\$s and you'll use perhaps at most some 16 cycles to clock out the data. So there is room. It appears you can run the I/O clock as slow as you want, too. So you can "bit bang" everything in your 8051 code (which makes bit banging really easy at the assembly level.)

There are lots of timing diagrams near the end of the datasheet which tell you what to do in each of its modes, in software. Is there something that you don't understand there? Normally, you just bit bang the clock line while also sampling (reading) the data out pin. There's more (as there is addressing involved and a chip select, for example.) But it's just minor details along the way.

EDIT: In answer to some of your comments below:

The 8051 *does* need a clock source. Usually, this is provided by applying a crystal between XTAL1 and XTAL2, plus a couple of tiny 30pF capacitors. I don't know which 8051 core you are using (I still have a hundred 80C32's from Intel, but I've used SiLab's [Cygnal's] 8051's too and there are more manufacturers than that), but you may also be able to drive one of those with a separate oscillator. You will have to check the datasheet for the device to find out various options. But you DO have to have a working hardware oscillator that drives the 8051 to make it work. There is no avoiding this requirement of the 8051. It needs a clock source of some kind. You cannot just apply power and expect it to run correctly.

Once the 8051 runs correctly, though, it's NOT the case that your ADC IC needs to have its clock line driven by such an oscillator. In fact, few would consider doing that and I don't even want to consider whether or not someone could make it work. (I'd have to read the ADC IC docs more than I want to, right now.) Instead, you just write software to manage the lines. You will have to program things so that the pins are properly configured, first. Then you will have to write lots of other software, some of which will be a subroutine or main-line bit of code that operates in a loop designed to extract a prior reading while initiating the next one. This is just very standard fare. You wire up a clock line, a data line, an address line in this case, probably a chip select (though this is optional, I believe) and perhaps something I've missed writing just now. Your software will operate ALL of them, changing the output pins properly and reading the input pin (data) at appropriate moments. The lucky thing here is that since you are driving all the other lines, you know EXACTLY when to read the data line. So it's really very, very easy to do.

None of this deals with the analog input lines. Given the difficulties you are having understanding something this simple and more "software-ish" than hardware-like, then I really, really worry about how you are going to properly design anything to operate the analog input lines -- where there is no question you will need to read other parts of the datasheet that does deal with hardware knowledge you need and will require some design knowledge on your part. Even the most basic analog inputs need some kind of conditioning and probably also protection.

Asking, "do you mean by inputting a clock to xtal1 and then outputting it through xtal2 to adc clock input," tells me that you are in for a world of hurt here. It's so completely off where your mind needs to be that I fear much more than just you figuring out how to clock out an address and clock in some data.

It's basic stuff that you want to do. But it is basic stuff that does depend on some fundamental knowledge you don't appear to have yet acquired. And if you are worried about a two week shipping delay, then this tells me you are in way too much of a rush for the learning you have ahead. Slow down. Allow yourself time to slowly acquire what you need to learn about. This is a great project in that sense, I think, in order to lift yourself up by your own bootstraps. But it will take time. You need to be prepared for that.

Comment: I will check the datasheet again tomorrow and report back with all the unclear parts if there are any. I am a bit new with this stuff.

Comment: Ok. This skill is a very, very frequently needed one. So what you learn here will apply in other situations you will soon find yourself involved within, I suspect.

Comment: I am software guy. Usually I just follow the instructions on some tutorial and write the code myself. This is going to be a hard one.

Comment: I'm also a software guy. Electronics is just a hobby. For embedded programmers, it is my firm opinion that electronics is a _necessary_ hobby. Not an optional one.

Comment: I also do this for a hobby. So I do not need crystal with lower frequency and instead I can output pulse (with lower frequency than 2.1Mhz) from a regular data pin? Should I use internal timer interrupt for this?

Comment: Just to be sure. It seems that I do not need any capacitors or resistors to use this with my 8051. Have I understood correctly? It takes two weeks for this chip to arrive from china and I would not want to wait any longer. Also I understood that I need to time the address bits with my clock pulse. Is this what you mean by 'bit banging'? How can I time the first bit with the 'rising edge' of clock? It now seems that the timer interrupt might not be the best way to output clock pulse if I need to send the first bit of address just before the rising edge.

Comment: You can do things very slow, if your application supports it. Bit banging just means changing pin states with explicit code instead of using a hardware peripheral. You could just write a loop of code. You could also use a timer event. But I recommend you try to learn this by writing a simple loop of code and don't worry too much about the exact timing here. (You probably will be using a crystal for your 8051.) The point is that your software makes the clock by changing the pin state, not some extra piece of hardware. (That doesn't mean it couldn't be done using a hardware peripheral. Just that

Comment: Does it matter if I dont use external crystal? When you say I could do this by hardware, do you mean by inputting a clock to xtal1 and then outputting it through xtal2 to adc clock input? Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Yes, now you understand what I mean by saying 'I am a bit new with this stuff'. Nevertheless I will provide you with a working circuit diagram and source code in two weeks just to show that it can be done. I noticed that there Is a 12.000Mhz Crystal on my dev board and it explains a lot. I thought that I was managing without it this whole time. Thanks a thousand times for your clarifying answers. I really have to find a good book on electronics after this.

Comment: Yes. I guess I do understand better. The 12MHz crystal is quite typical for an 8051. So that's no surprise. And no, you weren't managing without it!! It is as essential as the power supply itself. Some 8051 cores MAY include an internal oscillator. But if you are really using a genuine 8051 core device, then it doesn't have one. What 8051 are you planning to use? A genuine Intel 8051 look-alike? Or something from SiLabs? Or?

Comment: Mine is stc89c52rc. A 8052 really. I have succesfully interfaced with a 16x2 lcd and actually found its datasheet really easy to understand. There should not be any problem on the microcontroller side

Comment: The datasheet says "on-chip crystal oscillator." But I think they mean that it includes a class-A amplifier that can be used, along with an external crystal, to form such an oscillator. So I'm pretty sure you need the crystal.

Comment: I read through the datasheet again. This time I googled everything I did not understand (almost all of it). The digital side of this adc seems to be clear now. However on the analog side I noticed that: 'The driving source impedance should be less than or equal to 1 kΩ'. However my LDR varies from 5k Ohm to 0.5M Ohm. If I understand correctly I need to somehow 'drop' the impedance while keeping the voltage the same before inputting to adc. Is this even possible?

Comment: This is why I wrote a whole paragraph to call your attention directly there. Not only that, but here once again you exhibit another issue in your writing that shows an ignorance that will lead you astray. The ADC needs a voltage presented. The LDR presents a resistance, not a voltage. So you misunderstand something fundamental here, too. You need to transform a resistance value over one range into a voltage value over a different range, and do so without causing the voltage value to have more than 1k source resistance to the ADC.

Comment: That is what I tried to say. It seems that I need to build a 'unity gain buffer'. However I have trouble picking a operational amplifier for this job. Can you recommend me a suitable op amp for this?

Comment: No, not a unity gain buffer. Different thing. You need to monitor the resistance and convert that into a voltage, if you are actually trying to measure the resistance value of the LDR (I don't recall anyone doing that, as they usually use an LDR in some kind of switch application and not as an analog input source.) Do you really need to read the LDR value? Or can you simply accept a digital input if there is enough light. What are you doing with the LDR, exactly? What is it there for?

Comment: I was thinking of using the LDR as varying resistor in a circuit that varies the voltage according to the LDR. The voltage is outputted to adc, but it needs to be put through a unity gain buffer so that the resistance of voltage source is not too high for the adc.

Comment: Missed my question. What will the software THEN do with the reading it gets? What's the intended use of the value? What does it do, or control, or feed into?

Comment: So LDR is in voltage divider circuit. Voltage divider circuit outputs the varying voltage to adc. The problem is that the LDR resistance varies between 5k Ohm and 0.5M Ohms. This is too large 'source resistance' for adc which requires source resistance of max 10k Ohms. I read that 'unity gain buffer' or 'voltage follower' could be used so that the voltage would remain the same and source impedance drops.

Comment: It will output the value to a 16x2 lcd of course. This is a 'simple' light sensor circuit you are desining with me. :P

Comment: Okay. So you just want to make this into a light meter of some kind. I see. I need to depart for a few hours. Perhaps you could ask this as a separate question then? Provide the details you want to achieve, including the fact that you want to display quantities with units over some range? I think long winded discussions like this are _discouraged_. But I'm just a junior here, so I may be ignorant on this point too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43768/discussion-between-horttanainen-and-jonk).

Comment: I made a separate question for this op amp one as you suggested: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251746/how-to-pick-correct-operational-amplifier-as-unity-gain-buffer-between-tlc1543cn